# Appropriate measure for AB in online marketing

Tags: probability, ab-test

In a usual online marketing set up - a typical application of AB test is:

```
impression / clicks = CTR%
```

I am trying to investigate a different set up:

```
revenue_amount / conversion = conversion_value (monetary)
```

Can I run a test on the metric 'conversion_value'.

The revenue is generate taking into account the number of conversions - imagine - in a subscription model set up.

I ask myself - does it make sense to run a test on this kind of value? The revenues and the amount of conversions are in intrinsically correlated.

Comment: Isn't the click-through rate (CTR) defined as clicks divided by impressions? You have it as the reciprocal. More to the point, what do you mean by "run a test"? A significance test? If so, what null hypothesis would you want to test? Or if you meant an experiment ("A/B test"), which variable did you want to manipulate and which variable did you want to examine as an outcome?

Comment: yes edited that, CTR is clicks/impression. But forget about that. I want to test the hypotesis that banner A is better than B in term of conversion_value. The test runs like that. A, B banners are the same: at the time t one of the B receives a change. After x days the test runs and they must be evaluated. So my question is: does it sense to use the metric revenue/conversions?

Answer (score 0):

If the revenue_amount and conversion are perfectly correlated, then you will get the same result for both of your test cases A & B.  This is not a bad metric by itself to know from a business perspective, but this will not help you differentiate between your test cases.

Comment: The correlation matrix of conversions and conv_value for banner A,B is: Corr_ab = (1,-1,-1,1).